# Changing class attributes when radio button checked

Tags: jquery

I have this code snippet

```
<td width="143"><b>Monday</b></td>
<td width="68" class="open select_open">
  <span class="jqTransformRadioWrapper">
    <a href="#" class="jqTransformRadio" rel="radio_m"></a>
    <input type="radio" name="radio_m" checked="checked" class="jqTransformHidden">
  </span>
</td>
```

The radio button has no value. However, I should be able to change the value of the class attribute of the `<a>` tag and the `<td>` tag above the radio button when it's checked.

Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: It is unclear from your question what precisely you want to do.

Comment: What tags/values/attributes do you want to change?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Note: There is only one radio button with `name="radio_m"`, so you cannot uncheck it once it's checked (without JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

You can walk trought you elements structure. `prev()` function returns the previous element before radiobutton, `closest('td')` returns the closest TD element which is your TD.

```
$('input[name=radio_m]').change(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.prev().addClass('...'); // adding class to link above
   $this.prev().removeClass('...'); // removing class to link above

   $this.closest('td').addClass('...'); // adding class to table cell
   $this.closest('td').removeClass('...'); // removing class to table cell
});
```

Comment: *Please* cache `$(this)`, `$(this).prev()` and `$(this).parent()`.

Comment: `$(this).parent()` would be the `span`. You should use `$(this).parent('td')`

Comment: Cached inner variable. Thanks for advice.

Comment: I don't know what exatly wan't OP. But `toggleClass` is option too here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='radio_m']").change(function(){
    if ($("input[name='radio_m']:checked").val() == '1') {
        $(".jqTransformRadio").attr('href', '[Your Value]');
        $(".select_open").attr('width','[Your Width');
    }
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: The radio button does not have a value, so `.val()` doesn't return anything (actually I think it may return "on" or "off", but I don't know if all browsers (or just Chrome) do that).  Also, you don't need to select `input[name='radio_m']` again inside the event, it will be `this` as it's the element you triggered the event on.  Also, `if ($("input[name='radio_m']:checked").val() == '1') {` should be `if ($(this).is(':checked')) {` or better yet `if(this.checked) {`.

Comment: Yes, Rocket's modifications are more optimized

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="radio_m"]').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this), $td = $this.closest('td');
    if(this.checked){
      $td.find('a.jqTransformRadio').addClass('addClass')
      $td.removeClass('removeClass');
    }
    else{
      $td.find('a.jqTransformRadio').removeClass('addClass')
      $td.addClass('removeClass');
    }
});
```

You can try something like this.  `$this.closest('td');` will get you the `<td>` that you want, and from there you can find the `<a>` tag.  Use [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) (or even [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)) to change the classes on elements.